# Regex to find email addresses that follow a keyword

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find email within text that is being followed by a key word 'email'

`preg_match_all("/(email<=)(\S+@\S+)/im", $input_lines, $output_array);`

my input data is

```
here is some text
that does not hi_there@welcome.co
but this email should be captured yes@well.com
```

so the email in the 3rd line should be captured

Comment: What keyword are you looking for? - there is no obvious reason in your question why line 3 would match but line 2 would not.

Comment: The word 'email' should exist ahead of the email address on the same line. updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex: `/email.+?\b(\S+@\S+)/i`

[Working Example](https://regex101.com/r/K0KKhB/3)

in php:

```
preg_match_all("/email.+?\b(\S+@\S+)/i", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

`$output_array[1]` will now contain your email addresses

I removed the `m` flag - as this changes the way `$` and `^` work which are not being used.

The breakdown of this is as follows:

- `email` this just matches the text `email`- the i after the final `/` makes it not care about case
- `.+?` will match any character other than new line one or more times, but matching as few characters as possible see [Regex Laziness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- `\b` will match a word boundary - that is between a word character and a non word character - see [Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(` starts a capturing group - because this is the first one, this is why it is found in `$output_array[1]`, if you had a second any matches would be in `$output_array[2]`

  - `\S+` matches anything that isn't whitespace one or more times
  - `@` matches the '@' character
  - `\S+` matches anything that isn't whitespace one or more times
- `)` this closes the capturing group

We could start a huge debate over whether `\S@\S` is the best way to match an email address - I think its good enough for this purpose, but if you want to go down the rabbit hole see here: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Yes sorry, I have now corrected - I will edit further with an explanation of how this works

Comment: @Theo great answer.  I've never used \b before, now I know how to use it.  I visited your working demo link, and replaced `\b` with `\s` which yields the same result, but `\s` does so in 53 steps and `\b` uses 86 steps.  This isn't criticism, just an observation.  For this small sample, the time/step impact is unnoticeable, but perhaps if Kal is doing an enormous string, this nano-optimization may be valued.  Just wanted to mention it.

Comment: @mickmackusa - that's a very good point \s is probably more suitable here - I will edit my answer and credit you, but leave my version with \b in place - as I do like to teach people rather than just write their regex for them ;)

Comment: @mickmackusa - as I was writing the update I realised that `\s` also matches newlines so it would not be good here - I am suprised that regex101's implementation doesn't - A working comparison of the two in php can be seen here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d0a52705495f8ebd13a40b5d2d376b4b3c6a311

Comment: @Theo The sample in the question makes no mention of capturing an email address that is on a separate line from the email keyword.  In your new/different case, I agree \s will fail.

Comment: @mickmackusa I realise they do not want to match email addresses on separate lines, this was to illustrate that `\s` breaks the fact that the regex will only match where keyword is on the same line as the email - if we can guarantee that the word email would only appear on lines that subsequently have an email address then `\s` would work, but if there is any chance that the keyword could appear within a line without an email - then `\s` could make it capture email addresses that do not have the keyword present.

Comment: @Theo ...rabbit holes abound in regex pattern creation.  Every coder needs to decide for themselves when enough is enough.

Comment: @Theo how would you deal with the case if the email is like `hello-world-there@domain.com`?

Comment: @Kai I have updated the answer to make it 'lazy' which fixes this issue